# Does itext support JPEG 2000?

Tags: itext, jpeg2000

I would like to package a jpeg 2000 file as a PDF. Does itext support this?
I looked at the repo on github ( https://github.com/itext/itextpdf ) but it is hard to tell if there is support. Googling didn't turn up anything useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mention Googling: when I Google for itext+jpeg2000,the first hit points to the API documentation: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Jpeg2000.html

Since you mention our GitHub repository: searching for jpeg2000 in that repository, points to the class with the Jpeg2000 implementation: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/Jpeg2000.java

So the answer to your question is: yes.

Comment: And if you'd consult the examples of [iText in Action - Second Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book), you'd notice that the [ImageTypes](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=183) example successfully adds a JPEG2000 image to a PDF document. Isn't there an expression that says "A good software craftsman never blames Google"?

Comment: Thanks, Amedee. Is the image re-compressed by itext, or changed in any way when it is added to the pdf?  I am hoping that this is not the case.

Comment: Also, which jpeg 2000 library do you use to parse the images?

Comment: Bruno, thanks for your reply, but I don't have a copy of your book to consult :(

Comment: @Jacko That's a lame excuse, since *all the examples from the book are available online* as well as several free ebooks.